# RepeaterView for syncfusion columnSeries in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

I have tried using multiple `columnSeries` inside `sfChart.Series` and I want to display column dynamically.

```
 <chart:SfChart.Series>
     <chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Series1.ItemsSource}" />
     <chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Series2.ItemsSource}"/>
     <chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Series3.ItemsSource}"/>
     <chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Series4.ItemsSource}"/>
 </chart:SfChart.Series>
```

Does anyone know how to Use RepeaterView for syncfusion columnSeries in xamarin.forms?

Comment: You should specify your exact problem / error. What did you try exactly and what didn't work.

Comment: This code worked but what if there are more Columns to display. I want to use only one ColumnSeries inside Series and display columns dynamically according to the binded List

Answer (score 0):

We have achieved the requirement by defining a ChartSeriesCollection property in view model. Please download the sample from [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/203166/ze/ChartSample1193229499).

Code snippet [Xaml]:

```
<chart:SfChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}"> 
 ... 
</chart:SfChart>
```

Code snippet [C#]:

```
chart.SetBinding(SfChart.SeriesProperty, "SeriesCollection");
```